# IF/ELSE Get-SPWeb

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am trying to quickly check whether a web site exists.  I seem to have an error in my `IF` statement, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax.  Here's my code:

```
$URLis = "https://ourdevsite.dev.com/sites/flibidyboots"

add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell -ea 0

IF ((Get-SPWeb $URLis) -ne 0){
    Write-Host "Site does not exist, so we can proceed with building it" -foregroundcolor green
    }
Else {
Write-Host "Site does exist, so we need to pick another URL" -foregroundcolor red
}
```

What did I get wrong?

Comment: try this: `IF (-not (Get-SPWeb $URLis))`

Comment: you could use ``if (!(expression))`` to negate, Martin. Its just cleaner, well, so I think

Comment: Awesome....the -not worked great!  Thank you @MartinBrandi

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all its $null, not 0. And second, if it is not $null it exists, so your cases are mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will work.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$url = "http://teams"

$w = Get-SPWeb -Identity $url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($w) {
   Write-Host "Site Exists" -ForegroundColor Green
} else {
   Write-Host "No Site" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: well, why not use ``if ($w)`` ?

Comment: You can write it that way if you want.  either way.

Comment: yeah, but why overcomplicate?

Comment: Why indeed. Better?